# How to insert new line using doctrine_query symfony?

Tags: php, sql, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have to use this :

```
 $deleted = Doctrine_Query::create()
  ->delete()
  ->from('orders')
  ->andWhere('user_id = "'.$_REQUEST["user_id"].'"')
  ->execute();
```

to delete a line from SQL in symfony, but how can I create a new line with this rows:

```
id|user_id|order_date|order_type|order_end_date|aktiv|fiz_meth
```

the name of table is: orders

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a new order using this kind of code:

```
$orders = new Orders();
$orders->set('id', $id); // maybe you don't need this line, if `id` is the primary key
$orders->set('user_id', $user_id);
$orders->set('order_date', $order_date);
$orders->set('order_type', $order_type);
$orders->set('order_end_date', $order_end_date);
$orders->set('aktiv', $aktiv);
$orders->set('fiz_meth', $fiz_meth);
$orders->save();
```

Be sure to replace variable name for each column.

You will find an other example on the second code bloc [in the official doc](http://doctrine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/en/manual/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#select-queries).

Comment: Not working. :-(
500 | Internal Server Error | Doctrine_Exception
Couldn't find class orders

Comment: Can you post your `schema.yml` in your question then?

Comment: wich one? I have 17 files named schema.yml. :-S ... 

This is the biggest:
http://callgirl.connect2001.hu:8080/config/schema.yml

Comment: The one which containt the orders table. But this schema is a propel one, why do you ask for a doctrine question then?

Comment: I dont know... I don't understood symfony system... I just have to make some changes in one... 

And doctorine? 'cos this one:
 $query = 'SELECT * FROM paying_meth WHERE id="'.$_REQUEST["ef2"].'"';
 $le = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getCurrentConnection()->fetchAssoc($query); 
I get that doctorine think from here... :-s ... I can get rows from database and i can update, but i cant create... I just wanna create new lines...

Comment: There is a major problem here. You shouldn't use Doctrine this way **AT ALL**. You should use class model and never, never, NEVER write plain SQL to query the database. If you whole schema is define for Propel you should have propel query and not doctrine. It seems that your project is **really** weird :-/ It will be hard to help you ...

Comment: I tried to connect to the database with this:
$connection = mysql_connect("SSS","SSS","SSS");  
  if (!$connection)  {  
  die("A kapcsolódás sikertelen: " . mysql_error());  
  }  
//adatbazis kivalasztasa  
$db_select = mysql_select_db("SSSS",$connection);  
  if (!$db_select)  {  
  die("Az adatbázis kiválasztása sikertelen: " . mysql_error());  
  }

However when I try to make a query it write to me: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) What the piggeon cr*p is this?

Comment: (my english is a bit poor, sorry.. :-( )